# can't get file input when submiting a custom form

Tags: magento-1.9, php, varien-file-uploader

I have used this extension [HOW TO CREATE A CUSTOM FORM IN MAGENTO ADMIN](http://astrio.net/blog/magento-admin-form/) 
to create a custom form in my backend and the custom form has only one file input.

when i submit the form, it return form key only. so please check my code if there is anything wrong. thanks

**AdminformController.php**

```
class Turnkeye_Adminform_Adminhtml_AdminformController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_registryObject();
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('turnkeye/form');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('turnkeye_adminform')->__('Form'), Mage::helper('turnkeye_adminform')->__('Form'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function saveAction()
    {

        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            try
            {
                if(isset($_FILES['general[fileinputname]']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['fileinputname']['tmp_name']))) {
                    try {
                        echo "im here"; exit();
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('fileinputname');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('csv')); // or pdf or anything


                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                        // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file in a folder the magento way
                        // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file directly in the $path folder
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'aramex' . DS;

                        $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['fileinputname']['name']);

                        $data['fileinputname'] = $_FILES['fileinputname']['name'];

                    } catch(Exception $e) {
                        print_r($e);
                        die;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/adminform/index');
                return;
            }
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('turnkeye_adminform')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
        $this->_redirect('*/adminform/index');
    }

    protected function _registryObject()
    {
//        Mage::register('turnkeye_adminform', Mage::getModel('turnkeye_adminform/form'));
    }
}
```

**app\code\community\Turnkeye\Adminform\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit\Form.php**

```
class Turnkeye_Adminform_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
         'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ));

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

**app\code\community\Turnkeye\Adminform\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit\Tab\General.php**

```
<?php

class Turnkeye_Adminform_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_Tab_General extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('turnkeye_adminform');
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('general_');
        $form->setFieldNameSuffix('general');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('display', array(
            'legend'       => $helper->__('Display Settings'),
            'class'        => 'fieldset-wide'
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('fileinputname', 'file', array(
          'label'     => $helper->__('Aramex Sheet'),
          'required'  => false,
          'name'      => 'fileinputname',
        ));

        if (Mage::registry('turnkeye_adminform')) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('turnkeye_adminform')->getData());
        }

        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

here its a picture of html source code
[image: Html source code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used wrong syntax in `AdminformController.php` for getting FILE data. Use below code to access different attributes for submitted file:

```
<?php
    echo "Name: ".$_FILES["general"]["name"]["fileinputname"];
    echo "Type: ".$_FILES["general"]["type"]["fileinputname"];
    echo "Temp Name: ".$_FILES["general"]["tmp_name"]["fileinputname"];
    echo "Size: ".$_FILES["general"]["size"]["fileinputname"];
?>
```